# ¿Como puedo formatear un archivo json para convertirlo en los valor a insertar en una tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, jsonarray

Tengo un archivo JSON extremadamente grande que quiero llevarlo a una de las tablas en una base de datos. El archivo contiene los Estados y Municipios de México. Se ve mas o menos así.

```
{"Aguascalientes":["Aguascalientes","Asientos","Calvillo","Cosío","Jesús María","Pabellón de Arteaga","Rincón de Romos","San José de Gracia","Tepezalá","El Llano","San Francisco de los Romo"]}
```

La idea es convertirlo en algo así

```
INSERT INTO `country_state_city` (`id`, `pais`, `estado`, `municipio`) VALUES(1, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Aguascalientes'),(2, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Asientos'),(3, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Calvillo'),(4, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Cosío'),
```

Comment: Qué estás usando en el backend? Porque podrías recorrer el JSON con un loop y realizar un insert en la DB en cada vuelta. País y estado deberían ser IDs si los vas a estar repitiendo.

Comment: ¿Qué version de MySQL está usando?.

Comment: Se puede crear un `INSERT` como indicas, pero muestra la estructura completa del JSON para saber con certeza cómo hay que acceder a los valores. Muestra un trozo del JSON desde el inicio, imagino que tiene al menos una estructura así:  `[{
 "id": 1,
 "nombre": "México",
 "estado": {
  "Aguascalientes": [
   "Municipio1",
   "Municipio2",
   "Municipio3"
  ],
  "OtroEstado": [
   "MunicipioX",
   "MunicipioY"
  ]
 }
}]`

Answer (score 0):

Muy fácil solo tienes que usar la función json_decode para convertir tu json (strig) en un array. Cabe mencionar que el json lo debes de poner como string. Sería algo así

```
$json= '{"Aguascalientes":["Aguascalientes","Asientos","Calvillo","Cosío","Jesús María","Pabellón de Arteaga","Rincón de Romos","San José de Gracia","Tepezalá","El Llano","San Francisco de los Romo"]}';

$json= '{"Aguascalientes":["Aguascalientes","Asientos","Calvillo","Cosío","Jesús María","Pabellón de Arteaga","Rincón de Romos","San José de Gracia","Tepezalá","El Llano","San Francisco de los Romo"]}';

$json = json_decode($json, true);
$id = 0;
foreach ($json as $estado=>$municipios) {
   foreach ($municipios as $municipio) {
            $id++;
            echo "INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES($id, 'MEXICO', '$estado', '$municipio');<br>";
   }
}
```

El resultado seria algo asi:

```
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(1, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Aguascalientes');
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(2, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Asientos');
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(3, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Calvillo');
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(4, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Cosío');
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(5, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Jesús María');
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(6, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Pabellón de Arteaga');
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(7, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Rincón de Romos');
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(8, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'San José de Gracia');
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(9, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'Tepezalá');
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(10, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'El Llano');
INSERT INTO country_state_city (id, pais, estado, municipio) VALUES(11, 'MEXICO', 'Aguascalientes', 'San Francisco de los Romo');
```

Te dejo la liga para el manual de la función por si tienes más dudas **https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php**